# Moq: Can I swap between mocked member/property behavior and unmocked member/property behavior?

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, tdd, moq, moq-3

I want to use one instance of a mock library I am using in a test class, however, for some tests, I may want to mock one of the member functions to do/return mocked behavior/returned value; for other tests, I may want the unmocked (native) functionality of the library.  Is there a way to swap between Setup in one instance (mocked behavior), and "UNSetup" (unmocked behavior) in another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built-in mechanism to do that, but *partial mocks* kind of let you do the same (with some limitations). *Parial mock* allows you to mock concrete implementation of the interface as opposed to interface alone, like this:

```
var partialMock = new Mock<ServiceImplementation>();
```

Limitations are that all the methods you possibly want to mock need to be virtual, otherwise Moq cannot intercept them:

```
public class ServiceImplementation
{
    public virtual int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public virtual int SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        return SomeMethod()*2;
    }
}


var partialMock = new Mock<ServiceImplementation>();
// we stub one method
partialMock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod()).Returns(3);
// and use other's real implementation
var value = partialMock.Object.SomeOtherMethod();
```

Problem of course lies in the virtuality; in case you can't make your members virtual this obviously won't work. There's minor workaround though - use real implementation as parts of stub setup:

```
// note we base our stub on interface now
var implementation = new ServiceImplementation();
var mock = new Mock<IServiceImplementation>();
// we call real implementation as part of return setup
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod()).Returns(implementation.SomeMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
MyMock.CallBase = true;
```

for any not set-up method the real implementation is called...